# Android SQLiteOpenHelper Open/Close/Cursor Management

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Just to input the "context": I'm new on android/java and accostumed to work memory more "closely", this raises to me some questions that could be stupid.

1) SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase() returns a pointer to a object already allocated OR allocates a new, independent object?

2) How to know if a object SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase() is working in a background task (thread)?

3) Cursor created from database.query are dependent and share memory with database object (will be freed if database is freed) OR is a independent object that could be used after database memory is free?

4) If java handles memory itself, when Cursor.close() and SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase().close() are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

1. **getWritableDatabase()** - Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.

Once opened successfully, the database is **cached**, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

2,3. A Cursor implementation that exposes results from a query on a SQLiteDatabase. SQLiteCursor is not internally synchronized so code using a SQLiteCursor from multiple threads should perform its own synchronization when using the SQLiteCursor.

4. Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid. Unlike deactivate() a call to requery() will not make the Cursor valid again.